# Scala Future return Type

Tags: scala, future

I have the following lines of code...

```
val a = Future { Thread.sleep(10*1000); 42 }
val b = a.map(_ * 2)
```

After sometime when I check the value of b, I have the following getting printed.

```
scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(84))
```

Above, b's type is Future[Int]; but in the documentation, it says Future's apply method always returns Future(Try[T]). The documentation and the above example contradict. Can someone please help.

Comment: can you add a link to documentation? In std lib I see `apply` definition:
`def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit @deprecatedName('execctx) executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T]` and it's according to your type.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/futures.html looks to be this @BorisAzanov

Comment: A `Future` is like a `Try` but asynchronous. A `Future[Try]` usually does not make sense since a `Future` itself may contain a failure or a successful value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post your imports and the documentation you have referenced.

I think best parallel to understanding this is:

`Try[T]` is like `Option[T]`, `Try[T]` is always `Success[T](value: T)` or `Failure[T](exception: Throwable)`, just like `Option[T]` is always `Some[T](value: T)` or `None`

It can also be helpful to use the Scala REPL for things like this. It allows you to easily see types.

I'm assuming you've done this:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
```

Now you have your two lines:

```
scala> val a = Future { Thread.sleep(10*1000); 42 }
val a: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> val b = a.map(_ * 2)
val b: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)
```

As you can see the type of `b` is still of `scala.concurrent.Future[Int]` as it maps the result of `a`, an `Int`, which happens to be `42`, using the function `(_: Int -> _ * 2):Int`.

And eventually:

```
scala> b
val res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(84))
```

From [this documentation of Scala `Future`s](http://Notice%20that%20the%2084%20you%20expected%20is%20wrapped%20in%20a%20Success,%20which%20is%20further%20wrapped%20in%20a%20Future.%20This%20is%20a%20key%20point%20to%20know:%20The%20value%20in%20a%20Future%20is%20always%20an%20instance%20of%20one%20of%20the%20Try%20types:%20Success%20or%20Failure.%20Therefore,%20when%20working%20with%20the%20result%20of%20a%20future,%20use%20the%20usual%20Try-handling%20techniques,%20or%20one%20of%20the%20other%20Future%20callback%20methods.):

> Notice that the 84 you expected is wrapped in a `Success`, which is further wrapped in a `Future`. This is a key point to know: The value in a `Future` is always an instance of one of the `Try` types: `Success` or `Failure`. Therefore, when working with the result of a future, use the usual `Try`-handling techniques, or one of the other Future callback methods.

Finally, to extract the `Try` from the future, either a `Success` or a `Failure`, from which we will get our result, or an error:

```
scala> b.onComplete {
     |     case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, value = $value")
     |     case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
     | }
Got the callback, value = 84
```

Comment: Hi @Randomness Slayer, yes you are correct. I feel, I got really confused by the string representation. Thanks for looking into this!!

Comment: @user3103957 there are a fair number of answers to your question, could you please mark whichever you feel most adequately addressed your question as the accepted answer, that might help other people looking for answers in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things here. When you create a `Future`, it is created using the apply function which is in the [companion object of `Future`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#apply%5BT%5D(body:=%3ET)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D):

```
def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit @deprecatedName('execctx) executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
    unit.map(_ => body)
```

So as long as the future is not completed, its type is `Future[Int]`. Once the future completes, the result type will be `Future[Try[Int]]`.

As stated on `onComplete` documentation:

> When this future is completed, either through an exception, or a value, apply the provided function.

Therefore when you printed the completed future, it already had the Success. If you will do the same experiment with a longer wait, and an uncompleted future you will see that its type is not yet success.

For example, the following code:

```
implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
val a = Future { Thread.sleep(10*1000); 42 }
println(a)
Await.result(a, Integer.MAX_VALUE.seconds)
println(a)
```

will output:

```
Future(<not completed>)
Future(Success(42))
```

You can see that example running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QU5jHlBuRxSrg8W6u1gDnA).

Let's now look at [onComplete](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete%5BU%5D(f:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit). The following code:

```
val a = Future { Thread.sleep(10*1000); 42 }
a.onComplete {
  case Success(value) =>
    println(value)
  case Failure(exception) =>
    println(exception)
}

val b = Future { throw new RuntimeException }
b.onComplete {
  case Success(value) =>
    println(value)
  case Failure(exception) =>
    println(exception)
}

Await.result(a, Integer.MAX_VALUE.seconds)
Await.result(b, Integer.MAX_VALUE.seconds)
```

Here we can see an example how to use `onComplete` when `a` should complete successfully, and `b` should throw, and this is exactly what we get. The output is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
42
```

Because the throwingFuture is completed first, it is printed first.

Comment: @user3103957, please read [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that a `Future[B]` contains a `Try[B]`, which is correct. I think you're getting confused by the `toString` representation here: `Future(Success(84))` is the textual representation of a `Future[Int]`. For a `Future[Try[Int]]`, you would have `Future(Success(Success(84)))` as the textual representation.

Comment: I think the a simple parallel example here is that `Try[T]` is like `Option[T]`, `Try[T]` is always `Success[T](value: T)` or `Failure[T](exception: Throwable)`, just like `Option[T]` is always `Some[T](value: T)` or `None`.